# add_rewrite_rule refuses to function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a custom redirect on my local machine using MAMP. From the Wordpress codex I have the following code as a simple starting point. No matter what I try I cannot get this simple solution to function as expected. I am running the latest version of Wordpress, I have saved the permalinks to flush the redirects and changed the theme to eleminate this as variable. My xampp has mod_rewrite enabled.

I simply want to redirect: http://example.com/?p=95 to http://example.com/leaf/95

The code is as follows:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
//I tried this version
add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]', 'top');
//I also tried this version also(not at the same time)
add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/?', 'index.php?post=100', 'top'); 
    
      }
      add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

My htaccess is the basic wordpress version and I am not using any plugins in my build.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should ask your question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ where more people may know the answer.

Comment: I don't think _external_ redirects are `add_rewrite_rule`'s business to begin with ...? That is for setting up internal rewriting.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the reply, I am trying to rewrite internally not redirect to an external location. I am purely trying to rewrite url parameters to a tidy url format and this code is directly from Wordpress codex add_rewrite_rule reference point. But no matter what I do I cant get this example working.

Comment: But this does not do a redirect from `/?p=95` to `/leaf/95` for you, you're aware of that, yes? You will need to see to it that the corresponding links use the second format in their hrefs yourself. With the first version of add_rewrite_rule that you have shown above, what happens when you visit http://example.com/leaf/95 ?